# $\int_B x^2+y^2 \, dV$ where $B=\{(x,y,z)\mid x^2+y^2=a^2; z=x^2+y^2\}$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

$\int_B x^2+y^2\, dV$ where $B=\{(x,y,z)\mid x^2+y^2=a^2; z=x^2+y^2\}$
*also, the region is delimited by the $xy$ plane.

In order to do this integral, I first took the integral of $x^2+y^2$ with respect to $z$, from $0$ to $x^2+y^2$, which gave me $(x^2+y^2)^2$. Then, I need to integrate this thing inside the circle $x^2+y^2=a^2$ defined by the cylinder. So I did:

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^a ((p\cos(t))^2+(p\sin(t))^2)^2 p \ dp \ dt = \frac{\pi a^6}{6}$$ but my book gives $$\frac{\pi a^8}{12}$$

Comment: @ChristianBlatter the exercise says $=$ but I guess it should be $\le$

Comment: @ChristianBlatter why the factor 2? The region is limited also by the xy plane.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter yeah but wolfram alpha is giving me this answer, I didn't integrate yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Your handling of the problem is correct, up to a factor $2$: We integrate over a full disk of radius $a$, described in terms of polar coordinates.)

I assume that the domain $B$ is defined by
$$B:=\bigl\{(x,y,z)\>\bigm|\>x^2+y^2\leq a^2, \ 0\leq z\leq x^2+y^2\bigr\}\ .$$
In terms of cylindrical coordinates $(r,\phi,z)$ this $B$ appears as
$$\hat B:=\bigl\{(r,\phi,z)\>\bigm|\>0\leq r\leq a, \ 0\leq\phi\leq2\pi, \ 0\leq z\leq r^2\bigr\}\ .$$
The Jacobian being $r$ our integral $J$ becomes
$$J=\int_{\hat B}r^2\>r\>{\rm d}(r,\phi,z)=\int_0^a\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{r^2} r^3\>dz\>d\phi\>dr=2\pi\int_0^a r^5\>dr={\pi\>a^6\over3}\ .$$